# UIImageView in PopOver not changing?

Tags: objective-c, imageview

I'm making an app and it has multiple button that when you press them it open a pop over view (using Storyboard.) The image is blank in IB (I set it that way) and my buttons are ment to populate the image view. This is the code I'm using:
`[popoverImageView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"telegraph.jpeg"]];`
Steps (in order run)

1. Popover opens
2. Above code is run

Some notes:
The image is case matched.
The image is built-into the bundle

Anyone able to shed some light?

Comment: Thats all the code I'm actually using D:

Comment: Perhaps a screenShot of your Storyboard then with the connections window open so we can see them all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. if you haven't read Apples [View Controller Catalog for iOS](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/ViewControllerCatalog/Chapters/Popovers.html) you should read it.
2. I would check your popoverImageView's `viewDidLoad`/`viewWillLoad` and see if it is clearing your View before it presents itself.
3. Check your popoverImageView's properties they may not be linked properly
4. Enjoy using the storyboard I find it a pain for Popover's

Without any information regarding the the interface for your Popover and the implementation of the function where you call `[popoverImageView setImage:[UIImage  imageNamed:@"telegraph.jpeg"]];` and your setImage function i can't be sure of your exact problem

Comment: you could post the code snippets i suggested as an edit into your post and we could work the problem out